# Transformation Matrix Problem 2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> I have the following Problem:[image]
>
> And I have also the solution of the problem
>   [image]
>
> However I cannot understand how do we get the vector $l(m_0)^B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote the elements of $ \mathcal B$ by $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4.$

Since $\ell(m_0)=1 \cdot B_1+(-1)\cdot B_2+1 \cdot B_3+1 \cdot B_4$, the first column of the matrix in question is given by

$$(1,-1,1,1)^T.$$

Comment: but by mulipying a number by a 2x2 matrix you get a 2x2 matrix. Then when you add the matrix with another 2x2 matrix you still get a 2x2 matrix and not a vector?

Answer (score 0):

You get it from the definition of $l$ given at the beginning of your question, with $a_0=1$, and $a_1=a_2=0$.  Substitute those values of $a$ into the matrix on the right hand side:

$$l(m_0) = \pmatrix{1&-1\\0&1}.$$

Similarly, to find $l(m_1)$, substitute $a_1=1$, and $a_0=a_2=0$.

$$l(m_1) = \pmatrix{2&-3\\-1&2}.$$

Lastly, to find $l(m_2)$, substitute $a_2=1$, and $a_0=a_1=0$.

$$l(m_2) = \pmatrix{-1&4\\5&3}.$$

Comment: how do we know that $a_0$ = 1, when we dont have the solution ? Where is that given? And how to subsitute A matrix by a number ?

Comment: The definition given for $l$ says that $l(\sum_{k=0}{2}a_km_k):=$ the right hand side. $m_0 = 1 m_0 + 0 m_1 + 0 m_2$, so to find $l(m_0)$, you substitute $a_0=1$, and $a_1=a_2=0$ into the right hand side.

Comment: You not substituting a matrix by a number, you’re substituting the variables $a_0, a_1, a_2$ with the numbers 1, 0, 0.